# How to convert an array list into a normal array and vice versa normal array into array list?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I need to convert an array list of object type into a normal arrays.

```
ArrayList<object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
list.add(4);
list.add(56);
list.add("two");
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

how can we change an existing array to an arraylist?

```
   String st[]=new  String[];
    Integer in[]=new Integer[];
```

how can i convert this array into an array list of Object type so i can have both this arrays in one arraylist?

Comment: What is the easiest way? Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29).

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience actually my question was not correct.in my old project there i used some normal arrays string and integer arrays i want to merge all thisnormal arrays into an arraylist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose arrlist is an ArrayList. To convert it into array,try the follwing code.

```
Integer list[] = new Integer[arrlist.size()]; //arrlist is an ArrayList
list = arrlist.toArray(list2);
```

FOr more detailed example try this tutorial :

[toArray method  usage](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_toarray.htm)

Comment: [Link only answers will be deleted soon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Add some description please.

Comment: thanks sorry for the inconvenience i have edited y question please check it

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
Integer[] arr= list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);
```

Comment: thanks sorry for the inconvenience i have edited y question please check it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils;
int[] intArray = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(list.toArray(new Integer[0]))
```

This approach will make two complete copies of the sequence: one `Integer[]` created by `toArray`, and one `int[]` created inside `toPrimitive`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toArray()`

```
    ArrayList<Integer>  list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(4);
    list.add(56);

    Integer[] arr=list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

arraylist can be converted into array using toArray() mehod in java.

Check
http://coderspoint.com/index.php?topic=7.msg10#msg10